# Understanding Copy Constructor and Temporary Object Creation in C++ When Passing Objects by Value

Tags: c++, destructor, copy-constructor

Given the next code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

class Person
{
public:
   Person(const char *i_Name = "Unknown", int i_Age = 0)
       : m_Name(copyFromTo(i_Name, m_Name)), m_Age(i_Age)
   {
      std::cout << "creating obj " << this << ".\n";
   }
   Person(const Person &other)
   {
      std::cout << "Copying from " << &other << " to " << this << ".\n";
      this->m_Name = copyFromTo(other.m_Name, this->m_Name);
      this->setAge(other.m_Age);
   }
   ~Person()
   {
      std::cout << "destroying obj " << this << ".\n";
      if (m_Name)
      {
         delete[] m_Name;
      }
   }
   void printDetails() { std::cout << "Hello, my name is " << m_Name << " and I am " << m_Age << " years old.\n"; }
   void setAge(int i_Age) { m_Age = i_Age; }
   int getAge() const { return m_Age; }

private:
   char *copyFromTo(const char *i_Source, char *i_Destination)
   {
      int sourceSize = strlen(i_Source);
      i_Destination = new char[sourceSize + 1];
      memcpy(i_Destination, i_Source, sourceSize);
      i_Destination[sourceSize] = '\0';
      return i_Destination;
   }
   char *m_Name;
   int m_Age;
};

Person birthday(Person person)
{
   std::cout << "person's address inside the function " << &person << ".\n";
   person.setAge(person.getAge() + 1);
   return person;
}

int main()
{
   Person person = {"New Person", 24};
   birthday(person);
   std::cout << "END OF PROGRAM.\n";
}
```

And the next output:

Output:

```
creating obj 0x61fea8.
Copying from 0x61fea8 to 0x61feb8.
person's address inside the function 0x61feb8.
Copying from 0x61feb8 to 0x61feb0. // [temporary object creation]
destroying obj 0x61feb0. // [temporary object destruction]
destroying obj 0x61feb8.
END OF PROGRAM.
destroying obj 0x61fea8.
```

Notice that the program creates an object as soon as we enter the function 'birthday' because the argument 'person' was passed by value. However, at the end of the function, there is another call to the copy constructor, and we are creating an additional temporary object that we destroy immediately afterward. Why do we need this temporary object in addition to the local 'person' object inside the 'birthday' function if we destroy it *before* we destroy the local 'person' object.

Thanks.

I tried google and saw that before the function ends there is creation of a temporary object but I did not understand why do I need it if I destroy it even before I destroy the first local object of the function. What was it used for actually?

Comment: `if I destroy it` Init a variable with this new object and it will not be destroyed. The function promises to returned a copy, it does it exactly. The copy is destroyed because you don't use it.

Comment: Assign the result of `birthday` to a variable, and you'll see the copy getting destroyed after the function returns.

Comment: There are two temporaries. One is the argument of `birthday` and another is the return of birthday. You don't catch the return so it gets destroyed immediately as well.

Comment: And right about now you will learn all about wonders of copy elision and return value optimization, which varies from one C++ version to another, and may or may not happen, in some cases, because of your compiler's whims. Welcome to C++.

Comment: This code has bugs in how it (mis)handles strings.  The `std::string` was created to manage the resources of a string properly.  I strongly recommend using `std::string` rather than bug prone manual `char*` string management.

Comment: Minor point: although your code doesn't seem to allow `m_name` to be a null pointer, in general you don't need to test whether it's a null pointer before deleting it. In the destructor `delete [] m_name;` is sufficient; `delete` knows about null pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your main function to:

```
int main()
{
   Person person = {"New Person", 24}; 
   //birthday(person);
   Person anotherPerson = birthday(person);
   std::cout << "anotherPerson's address in main " << & anotherPerson << std::endl;
   std::cout << "END OF PROGRAM.\n";
}
```

You will see that the address of your "second temporary" will be the same as the local variable `anotherPerson`.

What happens:
If a function must return a value, it must be valid after the function has left its scope. Current C++ guarantees that these copy will be elided and the "new" place for your local variable ( here in the scope of `main` ) will be used for this "copy" which is in fact no copy anymore. This kind of optimization is called [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

It is quite interesting that an unused return value produces also a unused temporary. But that is not anything which the C++ standard tells us. This is only an observation of the compiler you are using.

BTW: Your init and copy of your string is fully broken and the variable is used uninitialized! Simply enable all warnings and don't try to be better as the standard behavior of `std::string` is already!

Comment: "_It is quite interesting that an unused return value produces also a unused temporary. But that is not anything which the C++ standard tells us. This is only an observation of the compiler you are using._": No, this behavior is specified and the compiler must follow it.